# java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request$1 in Spring Cloud Function

Tags: spring, jetty, spring-cloud, embedded-jetty, spring-cloud-function

[Sample repo available on Github](https://github.com/codependent/spring-serverless-gcp).

Given this simple Spring Cloud Function application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringServerlessGcpApplication{

    private val random = SecureRandom()

    @Bean
    fun uppercase(): (String) -> String = { it.uppercase(Locale.getDefault()) }

    @Bean
    fun random(): (String) -> String = { "$it${random.nextDouble()}" }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringServerlessGcpApplication>(*args)
}
```

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=uppercase|random
```

I can invoke it passing a String:

```
$>curl -X POST http://localhost:8080 -d 'Hello'
$>"HELLO0.8119601710812162"%
```

However if the String contains a space character it throws an exception, why?

```
$>curl -X POST http://localhost:8080 -d 'Hello world'
```

```
Mar 30, 2022 9:17:45 AM com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.HttpFunctionExecutor service
SEVERE: Failed to execute org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request$1 cannot be cast to class [B (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request$1 is in unnamed module of loader org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm @3fa87583; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.springframework.messaging.converter.StringMessageConverter.convertFromInternal(StringMessageConverter.java:60)
        at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:185)
        at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.SmartCompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(SmartCompositeMessageConverter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertInputMessageIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1282)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertInputIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:696)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.lambda$andThen$0(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:623)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:699)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:551)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.FunctionInvoker.service(FunctionInvoker.java:98)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher.service(GcfJarLauncher.java:53)
        at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.HttpFunctionExecutor.service(HttpFunctionExecutor.java:69)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker$NotFoundHandler.handle(Invoker.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use curl correctly.

if you are sending a POST, you'll only need the one of the `--data*` options, and you won't need the `-X POST` portion.

If you have anything that needs encoding, use the `--data-urlencode` version of the command line option.

```
$ curl --data-urlencode "Hello World" http://localhost:8080
```

which is the equivalent of

```
$ curl --data "Hello%20World" http://localhost:8080
```

But this doesn't really fix the root issue, as your `uppercase` and `random` functions are causing this issue.

They should produce sane values, and in your project, it's expecting a result of `Content-Type` that is `application/json`.

The signature of your function should match ...

```
Function<Message<BufferedReader>, Message<byte[]>> function;
```

Your functions are instead returning a raw internal Jetty class on `Request` that implements the request specific Jetty `HttpInput` class (that is what `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request$1` is).

As a result the `MessageConverter` list goes through ...

1. `JsonMessageConverter` - skips, as it's not a valid message in format `application/json`
2. `ByteArrayMessageConverter` - skips, as it's not a `byte[]`
3. `StringMessageConverter` - fails when it attempts to convert this raw `Request$1` to a `byte[]`

Comment: Er… there’s something I’m missing, the functions return a String:  (String) -> String. Besides they work for “mystring” but not for “my string”…

Comment: Added some details about your use of curl.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it looks like a bug in the Spring library for GCP functions to me.

It attempts to find the right converter for some generic payload when you send the request. In your case, you are sending a String.

As Joakim Erdfelt mentioned, Spring attempts a conversion through each MessageConverter. When you write "hello", the JsonMessageConverter actually succeeds! The JsonMessageConverter checks for a Reader object (which the Request object extends) and attempts to parse its payload as JSON.

The Gson parser being used considers "hello" to be valid JSON and "hello world" to not be valid (I'm not really sure why, given that both look invalid to me). By parsing it and returning it early, we avoid what seems to be a bug in the StringMessageConverter.

However, when you send "hello world", the gson parser does not save us and we end up hitting the StringMessageConverter, which does not know how to handle the Request object, and attempts to cast it to a byte array, which inevitably fails.

Here's an example bean that would work. It simply returns the request to the caller so you can change it as you want.

```
@Bean
public Function<BufferedReader, String> gcpFunction() {
    return (reader) -> reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Yes, I defined a Spring Bean with a BufferedReader input as Joakim mentioned. (The return object is for you to decide, but if you're testing things then just choose String to keep it simple).  

```@Bean  
    public Function<BufferedReader, String> gcpFunction() {  
        return (reader) -> reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());  
    }  
```  

This function takes the request input and simply returns it to the caller (although it's untested)

Comment: Formatting is bad in the comments, so I edited my reply so you can see it more clearly. Hope it helps!